# Faced a problem. There are queries in the database, but I don’t understand how to make it in one file

Tags: php, sql

First request.
If product_id has only one option_id equal to 10063 and does not have 10101 then write TEXT-1 to the database

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET oct_stickers = IF(product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "ocfilter_option_value_to_product WHERE option_id IN ('10063', '') GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1), 'TEXT-1', '')");
```

Second request.
If product_id has only one option_id equal to 10101 and does not have 10063 then write to TEXT-2 database

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET oct_stickers = IF(product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "ocfilter_option_value_to_product WHERE option_id IN ('10101', '') GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1), 'TEXT-2', '')");
```

Third request.
If product_id has exactly two option_id - 10101 and 10063 then write to TEXT-3 database

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET oct_stickers = IF(product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "ocfilter_option_value_to_product WHERE option_id IN ('10101', '10063') GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2), 'TEXT-3', '')");
```

Sorry, I'm not a programmer. I wrote this request for two days. That's all I had the knowledge for :(
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using IF's  you can use one `CASE WHEN` like

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product 
SET oct_stickers = CASE WHEN
                      product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "ocfilter_option_value_to_product WHERE option_id IN ('10063', '') GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) THEN  'TEXT-1'

WHEN product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "ocfilter_option_value_to_product WHERE option_id IN ('10101', '') GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) THEN  'TEXT-2'
WHEN product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "ocfilter_option_value_to_product WHERE option_id IN ('10101', '10063') GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) THEN 'TEXT-3'
ELSE '' END ");
```

Comment: CASE WHEN I did not know... I will study.
And in general I need to study requests ...
Thank you very much sir!